# How to loop through all register api routes?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have this function:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new PersonDbInitializer());

        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

The WebApiConfig is:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", 
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

At some point in the code I want to loop through all register api routes.
Any idea how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration` is static and you can get all routes with

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes


foreach (System.Web.Http.Routing.IHttpRoute route in GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes)
{
}
```

Comment: This does not include attribute routes